# Outlook web mail, when I change the timezone, I received "Cannot localize the default folders"

Tags: email, outlook, timezone

The localization operation of the default folders of 
mailbox "apcprd01.prod.exchangelabs.com/Microsoft 
Exchange Hosted Organizations/sct-15-1-485-9- 
msonline-outlook-dc1a2.templateTenant/puid- 
00030000DE174F34" failed:Cannot localize the default 
folders.[Please check the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKrJ6.png)

Answer (score 0):

This problem persist when you try to import the mailbox from another email client that has the folder in some other language. So after imported when you try to change the language, you'll see the above error.

The best solution to this problem is to **rename the folder as same as its default folder and then try importing again**.

The Default folders are: Inbox, Sent Items, Deleted Items folders, Drafts.